# Split a line of strings into strings consisting of two characters

Tags: c#, regex, linq, stream

I am reading in a text file which consists of a grid of alpha-numeric values (see below).

```
IQQQQQ
WG2223
S22228
D22223
```

Currently these values are looped through and each character sent to a switch case. This switch then reads that character and outputs a given result. The code for this process is as follows.

```
private void LoadLevel(Stream stream)
{
     List<string> lines = new List<string>();
     uint width;

     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
     {
           string line = reader.ReadLine();
           width = (uint)line.Length;

           while (line != null)
           {
                lines.Add(line);    
                line = reader.ReadLine();
           }
    }

    tiles = new Tile[width, lines.Count];

    for (int y = 0; y < Height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Width; ++x)
        {
             char type = lines[y][x];
             tiles[x, y] = LoadTile(type, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code I retrieve the text file and store each line in a list and then loop through each line and extract each character at a given point in the grid. Rather than extract a single character I would like to extract two characters at the same time and pass this to the LoadTile function.

As an example take the first line of the grid.

```
IQQQQQ
```

I would like to split this line into three strings each two characters long and then pass that to LoadTile and then continue looping through the remainder of the grid. However I do not know where to begin to attempt to achieve this task. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first off you'll propably want to change the signature of `LoadTile` from `LoadTile(char, int, int)` to `LoadTile(string, int, int)`.  Then change the calculation of the width to

```
width = line.Length/2;
```

Of course if any line has an odd number of characters you'll lose the last character.  Additionally if any line after the first is shorter you'll have exceptions and if it is longer you'll lose the additional data.

Then you can loop through like this and take substrings.

```
for (int y = 0; y < Height; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < Width; ++x)
    {
         string type = lines[y].Substring(x*2,2);
         tiles[x, y] = LoadTile(type, x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've accepted your comment as the answer as your solution was the quickest to implement around the existing approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var str = "IQQQQQ";
var arr = Regex.Matches(str, "..").Cast<Match>().ToArray().Select(u => u.Value);
// arr[0] = "IQ" 
// arr[1] = "QQ"
// arr[2] = "QQ"
```

Comment: RegEx seems overkill for this

Comment: @DavidG I know, but, though, I code C# well, when I have IDE, I don't remember much of signature of trivial methods as I don't code much in C# as I do in JS but I know `Regex` class, so the result :)

Comment: Try LinqPad, awesome for knocking up quick C# (and VB.Net) code.

Comment: Yeah, it's free but very cheap if you also want IntelliSense.

Comment: @DavidG I would definitely buy, when I start working :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you get a substring:

```
var item = source.Substring(i * 2, 2);
```

You can split to array in one line:

```
var split = Enumerable.Range(0,3).Select(i=>source.Substring(i * 2, 2)).ToArray();

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var item = split[i];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using LinQ. Try doing this for every line:

```
//Converts the string to a List of strings
List<string> stringArray = line.ToCharArray().Select(c=>c.ToString()).ToList();
//Iterates over the list and concats every pair of elements
List<string> result = stringArray.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2, x => x.value).Select(pair => pair.Aggregate((s1,s2) => s1 + s2)).ToList();
```